# How to convert blank spaces to zero values (unix)

Tags: unix, replace, whitespace

I have this tab-delimited file content:

```
Chr10_16           0.54    1.00
Chr10_51   1.00    1.00    1.00
Chr1_104   0.37    0.75    1.00
Chr1_105                   0.94
Chr1_109           1.00
```

I would like to convert it to:

```
Chr10_16    0      0.54    1.00
Chr10_51   1.00    1.00    1.00
Chr1_104   0.37    0.75    1.00
Chr1_105    0       0      0.94
Chr1_109    0      1.00    0
```

I tried different commands, but they didn't work as I expected. E.g.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"} {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~ /^ *$/) $i = 0 }; 1'
```

or

```
tr '\t' '0'
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
sed -e 's/\t\t/\t0\t/g' -e 's/\t\t/\t0\t/g' -e 's/^\t/0\t/' -e 's/\t$/\t0/' file
```

That is...

- replace all occurrences of adjacent tabs with a zero sandwiched between two tabs

  - This needs to be done twice because `sed` won't match on replaced content.  So if you have 3 adjacent tabs, only one of the two gaps would be filled otherwise.
- insert a 0 at the beginning of the line if it starts with a tab
- append a 0 at the end of the line if it ends with a tab

Comment: Using twice your command, I got zeros for the 2 and 3 columns, but not for the last one....

Comment: Try again with the updated code.  It's working on my machine.

Comment: Also, make sure that you actually have a tab at the end of the line that appears to get missed.  I actually made that mistake myself at one point. :)

Comment: It did not work for the last column....I did not understand about the tab at the end of the line....sorry

Comment: I mean if you have `1\t2\t3\t4\t`, you have 5 columns and the 5th "cell" is blank. If you have `1\t2\t3\t4`, you have only 4 columns. Therefore, if you left out the `\t` at the end of the line in the file, then there's no empty "cell" for the code to fill.

Comment: So the issue is the last column, but I do have tab in the last column....If I understood correctly....thanks for your help! I already converted blank space to tabs for the entire file...

Comment: It's working perfectly for me.  It even works for a row consisting of tabs only.  What editor are you using to edit the file?  I'm using `vi`.  Some editors strip trailing whitespace.  Is it possible that your editor is doing this?  Try `cat file | tr "\t" "#"`.  This will show you where all of the tabs are.

Comment: `cat -te file` will show you where the tabs and EOL are.